# derived class custom serialization

Tags: .net

I have class A which has custom serialization implemented

And i have class B,C & D derived from class A, It is required to implement ISerializable on derived class as base has implemented custom serialization.

Is it something i must implement? or am i missing some piece of technology that can let me use default serialization using [serializable] attribute on derived class in this case.

If have you faced similar situation could you please share some experience.

I do not have just B,C,D in real life i have around 20 different classes being used to pass around A to different applications and services.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you have custom serialization implemented. If you use reflection, list all field/properties - then propably all required code is in class "A".

But if the class "A" serialize only field/properties from "A" class, then you need additional operation in derived classes.

Comment: it is serializing certain properties, no reflection method is used.